# Factorial Recursion, answer doesn't make sense on paper?

Tags: java, recursion

So I was on codingbat doing recursion excercises and I ran into this

```
  public int factorial(int n) {
  if (n == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

I don't understand how this works on paper. as 1 returns 1 thats fine, 2 returns 2, thats fine, 3 returns 6 thats fine, but then factorial(4) returns 24? factorial(5) returns 120?

It doesn't make sense because it is doing it from the last answer of n I assume but not minusing 1? But passes all the tests. So it does 6*4 = 24, rather than 4x(n-1) which wouldn't equal 24? Help?

Comment: The problem here is not your code, but your mathematical understanding of what _factorial_ actually is.  Note that `24 = 4! = 4 * 3! = 4 * 3 * 2! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1`.

Comment: The code says: `return n * factorial(n-1);` but you are instead reading it as `return n * (n-1);`. These are not the same.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about mathematics terminology not programming

Comment: @Ivan I don't thin the op understands how recursion works.

Answer (score 1):

For any factorial(n), it is computed as n x (n-1) x (n-2) x ... x 1

So for factorial(4) that will be 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24

Recursion is mostly introduced using factorial as an example, so to visualize it will look like

```
fact(4) = 4 x fact(3)
        = 4 x 3 x fact(2)
        = 4 x 3 x 2 x fact(1)
        = 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24
```

The recursion repeats until it hits the "anchor" which is the base case of 1

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to understand recursion, it's good to picture a stack. Every time we're calling `return n * factorial(n - 1)` we are pushing a value down the stack so we can retrieve it after we're done computing the `factorial(n - 1)` call. And so on so forth.

```
factorial(5)
= 5 * factorial(4)
= 5 * 4 * factorial(3)
= 5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(2)
= 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 *factorial(1)
= 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
= 120
```

Comment: Hint. dont use images for text. Screen shots are your last resort, not your first. And most likely, you just took that screen shot from some page without attributing to it anyway. Not appreciated.